# Refused to run the Java-script Issue with Redirection from Lightning Web Component to Lightning App Builder page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-app-builder

I'm facing issue when I click link in the Lightning web component to custom built Lightning App builder page( Type is App page).

Error In the Image: "**Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-2fe344e1-42d2-3e31-1d83-50bbdae51e81' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval' *.canary.lwc.dev *.visualforce.com https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/ https://static.lightning.force.com". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.**"

see in the code below

```
openMyCustomView(event){
        let value1 =  event.currentTarget.parentElement.dataset.value1;
        let value2 = event.currentTarget.parentElement.dataset.value2;
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url : '/lightning/n/CustomAppBuilderPage?c__param1='+value1+'&c__param2='+value2
            }
        });        
    }
```

I am facing the issue in the console see in the below image.

[image]
Although this error is showing up in the console, I'm able to redirect on the custom lightning app page, but this redirection doesn't work on IE and Edge.Please help me on the above issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think type `standard_webpage` is applicable only for external URLs and Lightning App Builder should have type defined as `standard__app`.

Comment: What error you see in console in IE11 or edge ?

Comment: i have tryed standard__app  but it is not working